# javascript: getting the id of the parent from a document

Tags: javascript, html

I am having some trouble to get the id of the parent of a document which is "iframe1" here. As you can see the javascript should be residing in the  "" section. Do mind giving me some ideas?

Yes, I know. I can insert the javascript on the top, but believe me i cant for some purpose because I am intergrating many other codes into it.

```
 <html>
     <iframe id="iframe1">
     <html>
         <head>
                <javascript>
         </head>
         <body>
         </body>
      </html>
      </iframe> 
</html>
```

Comment: Is the content of the iframe coming from the same domain as the parent document?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the frame is on the same domain as the parent, you can use [`.frameElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.frameElement) to get a reference to the containing iframe.  If it's not on the same domain, security restrictions will prevent you from accessing the parent document.

```
var frameId = window.frameElement.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

add a `name` attribute to the iframe. Then you should be able to call `window.name` in javascript.

e.g.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="iframe1" name="iframe1" src="x.html">
        </iframe> 
   </body>
</html>
```

x.html

```
<html>         
     <head></head>
        <body>
          <script type="text/javascript">alert(window.name);</script>
        </body>
</html>
```